# jQuery infinite function execution

Tags: javascript, jquery

We want to know if it is possible to have a function using jQuery to inspect a number of elements and, depending on the types assigned to them by one click, perform other functions. Basically, a function that would run forever, while the user does not refresh the page.

The idea is not to depend on events clicks to perform a function, but the classes assigned to a specific element.

For example:

```
$("td.gantt").each(function() {
    if($(this).hasClass("oper")) {
       //execute a serie of functions
    }
    if($(this).hasClass("preop")) {
      //execute a serie of functions
    }
});
```

The above is executed once, and we need to run all the time.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

```
// define a function...
function ganttEach() {
  $("td.gantt").each(function() {
    // ...
  });
}

// ...repeat it once every second
window.setInterval(ganttEach, 1000);
```

You can't "let it run all the time" (like, in a `while(true)` loop) because JavaScript is single-threaded and blocking the thread means your *other* code will never run. `setInterval()` makes sure there are necessary "gaps" for other code to execute.

`setInterval()` returns an ID that you can store in a variable and feed to `clearInterval()` at some point to make it stop again.

---

If you want to make sure that every new iteration of your function starts only *after* the previous one has really finished, use `setTimeout()` instead:

```
// define a self-repeating function...
function ganttEach() {
  $("td.gantt").each(function() {
    // ...
  });
  window.setTimeout(ganttEach, 1000); // calls itself again in one second
}

// ...initiate self-repeating function
ganttEach();
```

You should probably include some way to stop the endless repetition here as well, like introducing a flag that's checked before the `setTimeout()` call.

Comment: @betacar: Bandwidth consupmption? IE Performance? How would I know? ;-) It's your code, you are the only one who can possibly know.

Answer (score 3):

It is possible, with [`setInterval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.setInterval). My advice would be to select the element outside of the repeating function so as to **minimize the overhead**.

An infinite loop would **lock the browser UI**, as it is a **single threaded** environment. Set interval, however let you add actions to the **UI stack** which will be executed after a given period of time. You can specify this period in the **second parameter** of [`setInterval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.setInterval).

```
// select the element outside
// to minimize overhead
$gantt = $("td.gantt");

// define a repeating action
setInterval(function() {
    $gantt.each(function() {
        if($(this).hasClass("oper")) {
           //execute a serie of functions
        }
        if($(this).hasClass("preop")) {
          //execute a serie of functions
        }
    });
}, 100); // repeat interval: 100ms
```

Comment: +1 for mentioning the benefits of defining the `$gannt` variable outside of the function.

Comment: @galambalazs: I love how my "+1" comment attracted two votes (one of them is your own, I presume), but your answer itself still has +1 only. ;-) Shouldn't I also up-vote the answer if I happen to agree with a "+1" comment? Hmmm... :-)

Comment: @Tomalak I upvoted because it has a valid point (setTimeout), which I thought about but then ignored. But after gave it another thought I realized that even if I would never do such a thing, a long jQuery codebase can cause hangups in the browser if the functions gather in the UI stack. And since you wrote it I gave you +1 because it should be highlighted. :)

Comment: And of course I also upvoted because it was a nice behavior which I'm not kinda used to in SO

Comment: @galambalazs: Agreed, user behaviour has degraded over time. It was a lot better in the early days when the user base was still relatively small. This very thing proves it: Someone besides yourself thought my "+1"-comment above was worth a vote, but could not be bothered to vote on your answer as well.

Comment: bandwidth consumption is 0, as it doesn't use the network at all :) Performance under IE depends upon how many things you do in a single repeated step. If you do a lot of things you can raise the delay between intervals. I generally wouldn't recommend using continuous background interaction btw, until web workers are not wide-spread.

Answer (score 3):

You can run your check every few milliseconds, say 50ms, using setInterval

```
window.setInterval (function () { 
  // do checks here
}, 50);
```

You might end up using a lot of CPU power if your checks are too frequent, or too complicated.

Comment: This solution has the advantage that can be run from the body.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure exactly what you are trying to do, but have you tried setInterval?  It will keep running if that is what you really want.

Answer (score 0):

```
window.setInterval(function () {
    // add your jQuery here
}, 100);
```

Comment: Code-only answers are low quality answers.