# Repeat a function infinite times

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

How can I repeat the `animate` function below infinite times? What is the best way to do it?

```
function animate(count) {

    if (count == 0) {
        $('.path').css({
            'animation': 'draw2 4s'
        });
    }

    if (count == 1) {
        $('.path').css({
            'animation': 'draw1 4s'
        });
    }

    if (count == 2) {
        $('.path').css({
            'animation': 'draw3 4s'
        });
    }

    if (count > 0) $('.path:first').one("animationend", function () {
            animate(count - 1)
    });
}
```

Comment: If I'm understanding the question, you just need to add an `else` to the last if statement and start over, like `else animate(2);`  Also, that's Javascript.  You're using jQuery to find element(s), but it's not a jQuery function :)

Comment: your best bet is to execute a function every X seconds ...

Comment: Or better... reset the count and run the function again....

Comment: @Adriani6 good point ^^

Comment: You haven't even mentioned if the code shown is working

Comment: I upvote your question, because of the genius question. But I have a question, why you wanna repeat execution of your function infinitely? why your function is not infinite function? why do you not use `switch` for better performance?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jQuery infinite function execution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3196647/jquery-infinite-function-execution)

Comment: Why not combine your three 4-second long css animations into a single 12-second long css animation, and let that run continuously? No javascript required that way.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by using [setInterval()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setInterval) function, you need to pass `2` parameters a `function` and `time` in Miliseconds to repeat that function,example:

```
var funcRepeat = animate("something");
var interval = setInterval(funcRepeat,1000);
//This will repeat your function once per second, 
// with 500 as value will be twice per second, 250 >  4, etc
```

If you want to clear the interval, (*thats why I stored it in a variable*):

```
clearInterval(interval);
```

You could also make the funcion inside it:

```
var interval = setInterval(function(){
   // code
},1000);
```

---

**UPDATE**
Looking at your comments, you could simply use **recursivity** with **[setTimeout()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp)** function:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {

  function animate() {
    // launch the first animation
    $('.path').css({'animation': 'draw2 4s' });
    // wait 4s
    setTimeout(function(){
      // Launch the second animation
      $('.path').css({'animation': 'draw1 4s'});
      // wait another 4s
      setTimeout(function(){
        //launch the last one
        $('.path').css({'animation': 'draw3 4s'});
        // finnaly wait 4s for the last one to complete 
        // and start again the function using recursivity
        setTimeout(animate(),4000);
      },4000);
    },4000);
  }

  animate();

});
```

```css
  background-color: #fff;
}

.crosshair {
  cursor: crosshair;
}

.bg {
  width: 40%;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

.path {
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  animation-iteration-count: 3;
}

@keyframes draw1 {
  0% {
    stroke: green;
  }
  25% {
    stroke: green;
  }
  50% {
    stroke: green;
  }
  75% {
    stroke: green;
  }
  100% {
    stroke: green;
    fill: none;
    stroke-dashoffset: 100;
  }
}

@keyframes draw2 {
  0% {
    stroke: red;
  }
  25% {
    stroke: red;
  }
  50% {
    stroke: red;
  }
  75% {
    stroke: red;
  }
  100% {
    stroke: red;
    fill: none;
    stroke-dashoffset: 100;
  }
}

@keyframes draw3 {
  0% {
    stroke: blue;
  }
  25% {
    stroke: blue;
  }
  50% {
    stroke: blue;
  }
  75% {
    stroke: blue;
  }
  100% {
    stroke: blue;
    fill: none;
    stroke-dashoffset: 100;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
        x="0px" y="0px" width="612px" height="792px" viewbox="0 0 612 792" enable-background="new 0 0 612 792"
        xml:space="preserve">
<path class="path" fill="none" stroke-width="1" stroke-dasharray="550" stroke-dashoffset="550" d="M240,260c0,6.627-5.373,12-12,12h-76c-6.627,0-12-5.373-12-12v-76
 c0-6.627,5.373-12,12-12h76c6.627,0,12,5.373,12,12V260z"/>
<path class="path" fill="none" stroke-width="1" stroke-dasharray="550" stroke-dashoffset="550" d="M271,296c0,6.627-5.373,12-12,12h-76c-6.627,0-12-5.373-12-12v-76
 c0-6.627,5.373-12,12-12h76c6.627,0,12,5.373,12,12V296z"/>
<path class="path" fill="none" stroke-width="1" stroke-dasharray="550" stroke-dashoffset="550" d="M306,346c0,6.627-5.373,12-12,12h-76c-6.627,0-12-5.373-12-12v-76
 c0-6.627,5.373-12,12-12h76c6.627,0,12,5.373,12,12V346z"/>
</svg>
```

Comment: @salimali Done, Usually worked like that, but check again,seems that the function, need to be stores in a variable ´funcRepeat´ and the pass that variable as parameter

Comment: @salimali Finally, I think that this time the update secction should be what are you looking for

Comment: I posted the answer, It done with an else condition.

Answer (score 0):

I think your function can be built in infinitely, Also use `switch` and cache of `jQuery` selection:

```
function animate(count) {

    var path = $('.path');

    while (true) {
        switch (count) {
            case 0 :
                path.css({
                    'animation': 'draw2 4s'
                });
                break;
            case 1:
                path.css({
                    'animation': 'draw1 4s'
                });
                break;
            case 2:
                path.css({
                    'animation': 'draw3 4s'
                });
                break;
            default:
                path.first().one("animationend", function () {
                    animate(count - 1)
                });
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Now, I'm thinking, you can do your job with **Vanilla CSS** `animation`.

Comment: @salimali, What does it mean _it's not working _? What is your exact program?

Comment: This is the fiddle, i want to repeat the animation infinite times. https://jsfiddle.net/ubwvxnj2/3/

Answer (score 0):

I can do that with an else condition

```
 $('.path:first').one("animationend", function () {
            if (count > 0)
                animate(count - 1)
            else
                animate(iterationcount - 1)

        })
    }
```